# Search query with two different fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I need to search in elasticsearch like

```
select * from tablename where file.content='xyz' and filePermission.Id='abc'
```

What query I need to add. Is it possible to give a filter to search query? I have set file.content as a default field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND SQL queries can be written as a "must bool query":

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                { "match" : { "file.content":"xyz"} },
                { "match" : { "filePermission.Id" : "abc"} }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine. Is it possible to add "filePermission.Id" : "abc" as a filter

Comment: yes, it is. indexing this field as not_analyzed will improve the performance

Comment: If I  need to give select * from tablename where (file.content='xyz' or file.content='pqr')  and filePermission.Id='abc' , What will I do?

Comment: Use a "must" and "should" construction